# Media Queries Don't Seem to Work

Tags: html, css

I finished developing my website and am now going back over certain areas such as font-sizes to make it responsive. In order to test my website in various different screen sizes I've been using Screenfly with my site files on locahost.

However, this code:

```
@media screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {

#logo {
    visibility: hidden;
}

#collapse {
    width: 80px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.snIcons {
    height: 30px;
    padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    left: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -250px;
}

.sidebar-nav {
    top: 170px;
    width: 250px;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
    text-indent: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.port-drop {font-size: 10px;}

.sidebar-footer {
    width: 200px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.divider {height: 420px;}

}
```

Now, ignore the fact that all of the sizes won't work on a mobile device, I'm aware of that. All I'm currently trying to get to work is:

```
.portdrop {font-size: 10px};
```

Anybody have any ideas on what the problem could be? I've tried resizing my browser window with the file open rather that using Screenfly. I have:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

In my HTML head. What could the problem be? The media queries are at the bottom of my stylesheet and the id's and classes definitely link up as I copy and pasted them all straight from the original declarations.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

EDIT: I've also tried:

```
@media only screen etc etc
```

and I've also tried:

```
@media screen and (min-width : 320px) and (max-width : 480px)
```

Comment: Try putting an `!important` on the end of your `font-size: 10px`. You can see if it's a specificity issue

Comment: I'd highly recommend using Chrome's developer tools to test media queries like this (there's a "mobile"/"responsive" mode, and you can inspect what styles actually get applied).

Comment: could be a typo...This `.port-drop {font-size: 10px;}` is not the same as this `.portdrop {font-size: 10px};`

Comment: I managed to get it to work by using the dev tools mobile/responsive mode. The styles weren't applied any other time, from changing window size or otherwise.